# How can I track the time spent and the number of words written in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to keep track of two variables while writing in Google Docs:

- number of words written per day
- time spent on a document per day

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: This may be of interest: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: @orshiro: In the same line as AI E., also may be of interest [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found a script which I will test now: https://github.com/jamietr1/google-docs-writing-tracker

Comment: @orshiro: Did the script work? If so, please add an answer sharing the highlights of the code.